# 360 Rotation in clockwise and anticlockwise start at 0 .the rotation is working but i want to stop at 90 ,180 ,270, and 0 degree when its near

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, if-statement

```
import {DesignItem} from "../../../entities/FDDesign";
import {AbstractMode} from "./AbstractMode";
import FDMath from "../../../helpers/FDMath";
import RotationRaster from "../../../helpers/RotationRaster";


export default class RotateMode extends AbstractMode {
    /**
     *
     * @param clientX
     * @param clientY
     * @param rasterRotation
     */
    public run(clientX: number, clientY: number, rasterRotation: boolean): DesignItem {
        console.log("xyz",clientX,clientY,rasterRotation);
        const newAngle = Math.atan2(
            clientX - this.itemCenterOnTransformedPage.x,
            clientY - this.itemCenterOnTransformedPage.y,
        );

        const baseAngle = Math.atan2(
            this.transformStartClientX - this.itemCenterOnTransformedPage.x,
            this.transformStartClientY - this.itemCenterOnTransformedPage.y,
        );

        const rotation = this.applyRotation(
            FDMath.normalizeAngle(
                this.item.rotation +
                FDMath.radToDeg(baseAngle - newAngle),
            ),
            rasterRotation
        );
```

//its a number consider it as angle for 90,180,270 then again 0 for rotation but it starts from 0..1..2.3.4 with floting values like 1.5..1.6..1.7..1.9 .2 .2.1.2.2 etc

```
        console.log("rotationIn ",rotation);
        return {
            ...this.item,
            rotation,
        };
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param rotation
     * @param rasterRotation
     */
    private applyRotation = (rotation: number, rasterRotation: boolean) => {
        
        console.log("RotationNumber", rotation);
```

//i am trying this but its work for clockwise and when i rotate-back its creating problem how to to it for antiClockwise.The mouse is fast i cannot stop on 0 degree once i start rotating it. its hard to come-back to its original position (check image plz)

```
       if(rotation >= 89.6 &&  rotation <=90.6){
            return 90; 
        }else if(rotation >= 179.6 && rotation <= 180.6){
            return 180;
        }else if(rotation >= 269.6 && rotation <= 270.6){
            return 270;
        }else if(rotation >= 359 && rotation <= 360){
            return 0;

        
        }
        else{
            return rotation
        };
       
        
        
        if (rasterRotation) {
            const raster = RotationRaster.getRaster(90);
            console.log("Roter", rotation);
            console.log("raster",raster);
            raster.forEach(
                (r) => {
                    if (
                        r.from > r.to
                            ? rotation >= r.from || (rotation >= 0 && rotation <= r.to) // raster around 0
                            : rotation >= r.from && rotation <= r.to
                    ) {
                        rotation = r.angle;
                    }
                },
            );
        }
return rotation
         
    }
}
```